# Java ContextPath

Tags: java, eclipse, contextpath

I have a project , How can I make Copy that project with other context name .
I change context name . at same time both project are not running. Eclipse show

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:721)
at java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:157)
at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:196)
at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:105)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:616)
at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:641)
at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:841)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:185)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What context path? Is this Tomcat or something? Give us a lot more detail about what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your eclipse's log, which is related to heap memory when you start your application. 
You need to increase memory size for eclipse:
- Open *eclipse.ini* in the Eclipse installation directory.

```
.......
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

- Restart eclipse
The bug will run away. 
ps: For your application, you need to provide more information.

Comment: That changes the settings for Eclipse itself. It looks like the question is about running a program (possibly in Tomcat) - the settings for that are elsewhere.

Comment: yep, but we only have simple console log, so base on what we was provided I think it will fix the bug

Comment: The console log is clearly not code running in Eclipse so no it won't fix it.

Comment: no, the error log is simply - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space. I strongly believe that it will fix the problem, then we need to resolve other problems

Comment: --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m

It is my eclipse ini Memory Distribution , I never get this error . 
i do not know why am i getting this error ??

Comment: So I need more log
- deleted all files in TOMCAT_HOME/logs folder
- restart tomcat, then provide whole catanina.out file